# Align an image and text to the right and bottom

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to right align an image and text to the right and bottom but I can't figure it out.

Please see the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markatremodelers/9rcnLb8n/34/).

```css
.right-bottom {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://www.objectpark.net/contentimages/MenuCalendarIconESmaller.gif" alt="live presentations" align="right" width="80" height="75">
<h2 class="right-bottom">LIVE PRESENTATIONS</h2>
```

Here's a picture of the result I'm trying to achieve.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to add a container element and set it to `text-align:right`. Then set the text and image to `display:inline-block`, so they will be displayed side by side to the right and bottom aligned, as the default `vertical-align` value is `baseline`, you can also change it to `bottom` if needed.

```css
.container {
  text-align: right; /* OR float: right; */
}
.container h2 {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h2>Sample Text</h2>
  <img src="//dummyimage.com/100">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its unclear right and bottom of what? If you are looking at something right and bottom of the viewport(visible area)
http://jsfiddle.net/8y0n09v8/

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="http://www.objectpark.net/contentimages/MenuCalendarIconESmaller.gif" alt="live presentations" align="right" width="80" height="75">
<h2 class="right-bottom">LIVE PRESENTATIONS</h2>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.wrapper {
  position:absolute;
  bottom:1%;
  right:1%;
}
.wrapper h2 {
  display: inline-block;
}
```